# Comparar Fechas en Java java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: java

Tengo un array de objetos que vienen de la base de datos, tengo que quedarme con el objeto cuya fecha sea la más alta, es decir, la última que se insertó.

```
2018-10-09 10:11:50
2018-11-01 13:11:22
2018-11-01 14:20:10 --> esta

private ThirdValidation maxRegister(List<ThirdValidation> process) {
    ThirdValidation tv = null, maxTv = null;
    String strDateFormat = "aaaa-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"; // Formato de la fecha  
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);
    try {
        // se comprueba el obj con la fecha más alta.
        for (int i = 0; i < process.size(); i++) {
            tv = process.get(i);
            if(maxTv == null) {
                maxTv = tv;
            } else {
                Date max = sdf.parse(maxTv.getRegistroModif());
                Date current = sdf.parse(tv.getRegistroModif());
                // El max es menor que el actual
                if(max.compareTo(current) == 0) {
                    maxTv = tv;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.warn("******************");
        LOGGER.warn("ERROR maxRegister()");
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.warn("******************");
    }
    return maxTv;
}
```

Da error cuando intenta hacer:
`maxTv.getRegistroModif()`, he comprobado que tiene datos y son `2018-10-09 10:11:50`, el error es:
 java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date pero anteriormente ya le especifiqué el formato:  `String strDateFormat = "aaaa-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";` // Formato de la fecha . Gracias!

Comment: Es posible que el error esté saltando porque en el strDateFormat tienes puesto "aaaa-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" cuando debería ser "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Comment: Bien visto, pero nop :(

Comment: Hice una edición, cambia también las "h" de las horas por "H", en mayúsculas

Comment: `hh` si que sería valido, mientras que `aaaa` no. He probado el ejemplo que pones `2018-10-09 10:11:50` y lo parsea correctamente. ¿puede ser que tenga algún carácter mas ese `String` que no lo permita parsear? [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: gracias, era por las yyyy y las HH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplemente cambiando:

```
String strDateFormat = "aaaa-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"; // Formato de la fecha
```

Por la siguiente:

```
String strDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"; // Formato de la fecha
```

Debería funcionar. También añadir que si lo que quieres es saber si es mayor, en el condicional cambia el `==` por `<`.

```
if(max.compareTo(current) < 0) {
    maxTv = tv;
}
```